# Upload data to Cloud Storage from external website

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I need to upload data from a public source to one of my Cloud Storage buckets. Currently, I download the data to my machine and then upload it to GCS. Being huge data sources (60GB in all, this week), I began running into problems to do it.

Is there a way to do it coding straight into GCS, without needing all the local downloading process?

**UPDATE:** I have tried using `curl http://originaladdress | gsutil cp - gs://bucket`. The problem is it would take 21 hours to do the whole process with 100 MB chunks, which is longer than it takes for me to download and upload the file. Is that right? Did I miss some parameter?

Comment: What is the public data source? If it is a Google Cloud Bucket, I think you can do a bucket copy, but I have not verified that with a public bucket (not using authorization).

Comment: It's CSV files in a government website, hosted in AWS. [This](https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ckan.saude.gov.br/PNI/vacina/uf/2021-07-27/uf%3DAC/part-00000-28580c78-8c6c-465e-a88d-49d6188a5e75.c000.csv) is a relatively small one. I could use the biggest one (60+ GB) or 27 of these, ranging from 0.2 to 15.6 GB - and increasing each week.

Comment: How many file do you have? Only one big, several small files?

Comment: 27 big files. The smallest one is about 154 GB this week! And there's one, unifying them all, which is 64GB this week. I don't know if it would be sounder to upload the 27 or the big one. Until last week I was uploading the big one on the GCS interface, but this week it crashed after the file grew, so I uploaded the 27 files on the interface also.